# Products still showing out of stock

Tags: product, magento-1, quantity, out-of-stock, stock-status

Previously in my Magento store I had set the **Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock** in the **inventory** to **5** so that if the quantity of the products reaches to **5 or below** it should **show as out of stock** and it was working properly. Now I want the quantity to be displayed according to the exact number and hence I changed the value of **Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock** from **5 to 0**. But even after changing the products are still showing out of stock when the count reaches 5. I have reindexed all the data and I have even cleared the cache after changing the value. Kindly let me know what should I do to **enable the products to show in stock even if the count reaches 5 or below**.

Comment: Have you check "stock availability" option set >> In Stock in Inventory tab

Comment: Have you verified you default configuration from System >> Configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to admin panal, go to Catalog->Manage Products->(Product)->Inventory
2. Switch to "Inventory" tab, check the "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock" is "Use Config Settings" or not
   [image]

Ref.: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-manage-stock.html

Comment: Hi @PY Yick that check box inside the product inventory is already checked as you have mentioned.

Comment: How about "Stock Availability"? Does it show "In stock" or "Out of Stock"?

Comment: it is showing out of stock but once i change the value of min qty in inventory it should automatically change to in stock isn't it .

Comment: I don't think it will. You can try to change it manually first.